# Rendering data:application/pdf Base64 encoded data uri to HTMLCanvasElement?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm wondering if it is possible to somehow render a data:application/pdf Base64 encoded data uri to a HTMLCanvasElement?

I need to do this because a business requirement is that the PDF is only accessible/downloadable once a user has paid.

Where I am with my code:

I am using jsPDF to render a PDF dynamiclaly based off of some input data. This is rendered as the user updates input.

I obtain a base64 endcoded string using that library's `const base64Data = pdf.output('datauristring')` method call.

I then convert this base64 string to a blob.

```
const base64 = await fetch(base64Data)

const blob = await base64.blob()

this.PDF = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

However, I'm thinking some of these steps might not be needed?

Would anyone recommend any potential solutions for rendering a PDF inside a `CanvasHTMLElement`?

Comment: [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) can do this, to do it yourself is thus also possible, if you have a big team, lots of resources and time.

Comment: Ok great. Where would I find documentation to achieve this... question tho, does the rendering on canvas come with the toolbar...I don't want any native browser UI.UX, just a flat rendering of the PDF page. No editing, downloading, printing etc. I say this because it's ridiculous not to be able to do this natively in 2021 - Firefox is a complete disaster on this front.

Comment: You don't have to include the full viewer, pdf.js is first an API with core methods to parse and render pdf files. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/ Regarding your rant, it's completely useless and disrespectful. The pdf.js library I linked to is built by Mozilla's team and they have made a great work toward standardizing this part of the web. Spitting on them here is truly insulting.

Comment: I found your comment equally flippant. Essentially, we can't render a PDF natively because Firefox will not allow us to turn off all of the toolbars for an embded object. This is totally ridiculous. We have to now utilise server capacity to convert raw input to the PDF, then the PDF to separate images for each page, save those images alongside the PDF and then send them to the user. Totally environmental unfriendly, and cost in-effective.

Comment: What are you talking about? You have to read and learn on the subject matter you're working with before going into spitting all over the place.

Comment: Yes, quite a lot. Firefox won't allow us to embed a pdf without all toolbars being hidden. So we either need to split it into images, or render it on a canvas.